# Finding unique records in pandas with multiple column combination

Tags: python, pandas, unique

Suppose I have this pandas data frame,

```
df

street_id district_id region_id value1 value2 
   1          6          8        7      5
   1          5          8        9      3
   2          6          5        8      0
   2          6          5        6      2
   3          4          8        5      1
   3          7          9        0      2
```

Expected output is,

```
street_id district_id region_id
   2          6          5            
   3          4          8       
   3          7          9
```

I want to select only the street records which are unique within a region. I can't just find the unique of street_id & region_id, since I need the district_id as well. How can I do this?

Here uniqueness of the street is defined by a street present within only one district of a region.

Comment: Is output correct? Can you explain more?

Comment: Yes its correct, what I want is unique street with in a region, but with its district_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [15]: df.assign(x=df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'] 
                       .transform('nunique')) \
    ...:   .query("x == 1") \
    ...:   .drop_duplicates(subset=['street_id','region_id']) \
    ...:   .drop('x',1)
Out[15]:
   street_id  district_id  region_id  value1  value2
2          2            6          5       8       0
4          3            4          8       5       1
5          3            7          9       0       2
```

or as [proposed by @Zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336814/finding-unique-records-in-pandas-with-multiple-column-combination/46337044?noredirect=1#comment79635107_46337044) a nicer and shorter version:

```
df[df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id']
     .tran‌​sform('nunique').eq(‌​1)] \
  .drop_duplicates(‌​subset=['street_id',‌​'region_id'])
```

Break down:

```
In [16]: df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'].transform('nunique')
Out[16]:
0    2
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    1
Name: district_id, dtype: int64

In [17]: df.assign(x=df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'].transform('nunique'))
Out[17]:
   street_id  district_id  region_id  value1  value2  x
0          1            6          8       7       5  2
1          1            5          8       9       3  2
2          2            6          5       8       0  1
3          2            6          5       6       2  1
4          3            4          8       5       1  1
5          3            7          9       0       2  1

In [18]: df.assign(x=df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'].transform('nunique')) \
    ...:   .query("x == 1") \
    ...:
Out[18]:
   street_id  district_id  region_id  value1  value2  x
2          2            6          5       8       0  1
3          2            6          5       6       2  1
4          3            4          8       5       1  1
5          3            7          9       0       2  1

In [19]: df.assign(x=df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'].transform('nunique')) \
    ...:   .query("x == 1") \
    ...:   .drop_duplicates(subset=['street_id','region_id']) \
    ...:
Out[19]:
   street_id  district_id  region_id  value1  value2  x
2          2            6          5       8       0  1
4          3            4          8       5       1  1
5          3            7          9       0       2  1
```

Comment: Ok, here is the issue, it shouldn't return street_id = 1, because it is present in multiple districts within the same region.

Comment: Let me check with the full dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain whats happening here? That will be helpful to learn. @MaxU

Comment: @ds_user, IMO the easiest way to understand it is to break it down into steps and to check the results...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Don't need `assign` and `drop` with `df[df.groupby(['region_id','street_id'])['district_id'].transform('nunique').eq(1)].drop_duplicates(subset=['street_id','region_id'])`?